# Bash: How to extract portion from the end of a line that's in a variable?

Tags: bash, sed, string, pattern-matching

In the context of a bash script, how do I extract the `uniqueID` from the `uniqueID_db.dat` part of URLs such as these, where the uniqueID can be anything, for example:

```
https://cdn.somedomain.com/fetch/uniqueID/uniqueID_db.dat
https://server123456.eu.somedomain.com/789/storage/uniqueID/uniqueID_db.dat
https://cdn.somedomain.com/fetch/6234449e1539130b/6234449e1539130b_db.dat
https://server654321.eu.somedomain.com/0123/storage/afd85b3f9ae5bc9/afd85b3f9ae5bc9_db.dat
```

Lines always end in `_db.dat` and it's the uniqueID before it that I'd like to extract.

Any line is in the variable `$link`.

Is this extraction possible with `sed` or some other tool? If so, how? And can you please explain the workings so I can learn?

I imagine something like:

```
echo "${link}" | sed '...'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this Q not appropriate or problematic somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-) link='https://server123456.eu.somedomain.com/789/storage/uniqueID/uniqueID_db.dat'
-) #.. Remove averything up to last /
-) uid="${link##*/}"
-) echo "${uid}"
uniqueID_db.dat
-) #.. Remove the suffix.
-) uid="${uid%_db.dat}"
-) echo "${uid}"
uniqueID
-)
```

There is a whole raft of these in section 3.5.3 of the GNU Bash Reference Manual.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

If you want the `uniqueID/uniqueID` pair, that can be done with a little more care. These Bash constructs look cumbersome, but they are preferable to starting external processes to edit a few bytes.

```
-) link='https://server123456.eu.somedomain.com/789/storage/uniqueID/uniqueID_db.dat'
-) #.. Extract the prefix.
-) pfx="${link%/*/*}"
-) #.. Substring the link from after the prefix.
-) uid="${link:${#pfx}}"
-) echo "${uid}"
/uniqueID/uniqueID_db.dat
-) #.. Clip front and back.
-) uid="${uid#/}"
-) uid="${uid%_db.dat}"
-) echo "${uid}"
uniqueID/uniqueID
-)
```

Comment: Your code would be easier to read without the `Paul--)` prompts.

Comment: I could script the whole thing, and show the output, but then it would not be obvious what the immediate effect of each line was. I would end up with a script that echoed `Running uid="${link:${#pfx}}"` and then `Now uid is ..whatever..`. Showing the actual terminal commands demonstrates I don't have any tricks up my sleeve. Maybe showing a script, and then a run with -x set, would be better.

Comment: I only suggest to replace the prompt `Paul--)` with a less distracting standard prompt like simply `$`

Comment: @Bodo I've had people entering a leading prompt like `$cmd` or `$ cmd` or `$cmd -opts`, and then complaining my command is invalid. I've had people entering a leading root prompt like `# cmd` and complaining my script does nothing. I've had people entering a leading prompt like `dir> cmd` and then complaining my script emptied itself. So I'm in favour of something that is clearly a prompt, rather than any shell-sensitive characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F '[/_]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

Or `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep -o '[^/]*$' file | cut -d_ -f1
```

or `grep -P`:

```
grep -Po '[^/]*(?=_db.dat$)' file
```

or `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(.*\/)([^/]*)_db.dat$/\2/' file
```